# Navigation sidebar in helpcenter suddenly disappears

Tags: bug, design, help-center

I noticed that the sidebar on the help center page about formatting suddenly disappears when scrolling down while a quote is displayed at the top. See for example on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), though the issue seems to affect all help centers.

[image: Screenshot 1]
Same page after scrolling roughly one line:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I think it only happens when you have a section "quoted for convenience from the full editing help".